# irq.h or irqflags.h disable interrupts Raspberry

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, interrupt, lib

I have Raspberry Pi Zero, and I try include a few libraries for this functions:

```
local_irq_disable();
/* interrupts are disabled .. */
local_irq_enable();
```

I installed these packages: `sudo apt-get install raspbery-*`
But my compiler gcc/g++ don't find this headers `<linux/irq.h> || <linux/irqflags.h>`. This function is so important. Where are these function? How can I include them?

Comment: Please show us the code where you include the headers, as well as the error message gcc gives.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <wiringPi.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    // #include <linux/irq.h> #include <linux/irqflags.h>
...

Comment: main.c:7:10: fatal error: linux/irqflags.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/irqflags.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: Compiler can't found this headers. And I can't past all code, because it's so long

Comment: You need to add that information to the question. (I tried to edit in the [necessary information](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24056874), but the edit got rejected. Apparently, adding the #includes and error message is "promoting a product".)